# Unable to receive packet using jpcap in WiFi network

Tags: java, networking, winpcap, jpcap

I want to send and receive packets in WiFi network.
using the following codes

To send packet.

```
int id = Integer.parseInt(text_device.getText().trim());
JpcapCaptor jpcap = JpcapCaptor.openDevice(devices[id], 65535, true, 20);
JpcapSender sender = jpcap.getJpcapSenderInstance();
TCPPacket packet = new TCPPacket(210, 210, 0l, 12l, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, 1, 2);
packet.setIPv4Parameter(0, true, true, true, 0, true, true, true, 0, 1010101, 100, IPPacket.IPPROTO_TCP, InetAddress.getLocalHost(), InetAddress.getByName(text_ip.getText().trim()));
packet.data = "Sample Data".getBytes();
Date date = new Date();
packet.usec = date.getTime();
packet.sec = date.getTime();
EthernetPacket ether = new EthernetPacket();
ether.src_mac = new byte[]{(byte) 1, (byte) 1, (byte) 1, (byte) 1, (byte) 1, (byte) 1};
ether.dst_mac = new byte[]{(byte) 255, (byte) 255, (byte) 255, (byte) 255, (byte) 255, (byte) 255};
ether.frametype = EthernetPacket.ETHERTYPE_IP;
packet.datalink = ether;
sender.sendPacket(packet);
```

To receive packet, i write this code in `public void receivePacket(Packet packet)`

```
TCPPacket tcp = (TCPPacket) packet;
String src = tcp.src_ip.getHostAddress();
int src_port = tcp.src_port;
String dst = tcp.dst_ip.getHostAddress();
int dst_port = tcp.dst_port;
String data = new String(tcp.data);
System.out.println("" + data + "");
```

It works when i connect two machines with LAN, but unable to receive packet when i connect with WiFi.

Can anyone suggest me, whats going wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the answer is related to this quote from the JPCAP FAQ:

> Q: Can I capture packets from a WiFi (802.11) network interface?
>
> The answer depends on what Operating System you are running and which
>   WiFi devices your system has. On Windows, you may not be able to
>   capture packets from some WiFi devices. Linux or BSD may have higher
>   probability of supporting packet capturing using WiFi devices.

You may have better success on the Google [discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jpcap) for JPcap if you share your precise adapter type and windows version details.

Comment: What do you suggest i should do now..because i have to use windows??